# Trying to set oversized image as navigation bar title. Width refuses to adjust

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar

I have an image/banner that I want to use as the title for a navigation bar. The image's resolution is 720x227 px. I threw the image into a `UIButton` who's frame I set as 79x25:

```
UIButton* titleImage = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,79,25)];
[titleImage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[titleImage setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImage;
```

The height adjusts perfectly. The width however is stuck around 250px and refuses to adjust no matter what number I put in, as you can see below. Can anyone see why? Let me know what other pieces of code you need to see.

[image]

edit: I've also tried to cut out the UIButton and simply threw it into an imageview like so:

```
UIImageView* titleImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 25)];
[titleImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImage;
```

However, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you resize the image so it will fit the navigation bar, there's no reason to load such a large image into memory when only a scaled down image is being shown anyway.

Your app will load a little faster to boot.

Comment: I agree, I am currently working on this. However, I'd still like to know why I am unable to adjust the width.

Comment: Its currently shrinking your image to fit. If you [titleImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit]; it will scale to fit.